# Is my proof that $x \mapsto f(x,y)$ is measurable correct?

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

Let $(X, \mathcal{M}), (Y, \mathcal{N})$ be measurable spaces and $f \colon X \times Y \to \mathbb{R}$ a $\mathcal{M} \otimes \mathcal{N}$-measurable function, where $\mathcal{M} \otimes \mathcal{N}$ is taken to be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the measurable rectangles $A \times B$, for $A \in \mathcal{M}, B \in \mathcal{M}$.

Want to show that the map $x \mapsto f(x,y)$ is $\mathcal{M}$-measurable.

I've written up my attempt below. It's mainly Step 1 I'm wondering if is right, as I've seen other proofs using Dynkin system instead.

---

**Attempt:**

We use bootstrapping:

**Step 1:** First show the claim for $1_{A\times B}, \ A \in \mathcal{M}$ and $B \in \mathcal{N}$.

We have that for fixed $y$

$1_{A\times B}(x,y) = 1_A(x) 1_B(y)$ is either $1_A(x)$ or $0$ depending if $y \in B$ or $y \in B^c$, and we see this is $\mathcal{M}$-measurable.

Consider still indicator functions. Assume the claim holds for some set $E \subset X \times Y$ and show that it holds for $E^c$. Also, assume it holds for $(E_n)_n \subset X \times Y$, and show that it holds for the countable union $\bigcup_n E_n$. I.e., that the collection $\mathcal{L}$ of sets for which the claim holds for indicator functions forms a $\sigma$-algebra.

The above can be shown using the fact that $1_{E^c} = 1 - 1_E$ and $1_{\bigcup_n E_n} = \sup_n 1_{E_n}$ Hence, $\mathcal{L}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. It is thus a $\sigma$-algebra containing the collection $\mathcal{C}$ of measurable rectangles. Hence, $\sigma(\mathcal{C}) = \mathcal{M} \otimes \mathcal{N} \subset \mathcal{L}$.

**Step 2:** Let $f$ be a nonnegative simple function, $f(x,y) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i 1_{E_i}(x,y)$, where the $E_i$ are in $\mathcal{M} \otimes \mathcal{N}$.

Then for a fixed $y$, $f$ is a linear combination of $\mathcal{M}$-measurable functions, as we've just shown, hence $\mathcal{M}$-measurable.

**Step 3:** Next assume $f$ is a nonnegative measurable function.

Then we can find a sequence of nonnegative simple functions $(g_n)_n \nearrow f$, so

$f = \lim_{n \to \infty} g_n$,

which is the limit of a sequence of $\mathcal{M}$-measurable (by 2) functions, hence $\mathcal{M}$-measurable.

**Step 4:** Now let $f$ be a general measurable function $f \colon X \times Y \to \mathbb{R}$.

Decompose $f = f^+ - f^-$.

We know $f^+$ and $f^-$ are nonnegative $\mathcal{M}$-measurable functions.

If we fix $y$, then by 3 we know the claim holds for such functions.

---

Is this enough? I've seen Step 1 argued using Dynkin systems, but I don't see why it's necessary considering the argument above. The other argument roughly goes:

$\mathcal{L}$ is a Dynkin system. It contains the collection $\mathcal{C}$, which is a $\pi$-system. Hence, by Dynkin's $\pi-\lambda$ theorem, $\sigma(\mathcal{C}) = \mathcal{M} \otimes \mathcal{N} \subset \mathcal{L}$.

So is $\mathcal{L}$ not necessarily a $\sigma$-algebra, then? Seems like it is, by the argument in Step 1, but maybe I'm missing something!

Comment: It's correct (though you wanted to write '$x\in A$ or $x\in A^c$' at second paragraph of Step 1. However, I guess, you can directly apply an argument along Step 1 for the inverse images of an arbitrary measurable function $f:X\times Y\to\Bbb R$.

Comment: Thanks. $y \in B$ or $y \in B^c$, right? Changed it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need this fact: For each $y\in Y$, the map $x\mapsto(x,y)$
is $\mathcal{M}/\mathcal{M}\otimes\mathcal{N}$-measurable.

Proof: Fix $y\in Y$. Define $\theta:X\rightarrow X\times Y$ by $\theta(x)=(x,y)$.
Let $A\times B\in\mathcal{\mathcal{M}\otimes N}$ be a measurable
rectangle. We have that $\theta^{-1}(A\times B)=\begin{cases}
A, & \mbox{ if }y\in B\\
\emptyset, & \mbox{ if }y\notin B
\end{cases}.$ In both cases, $\theta^{-1}(A\times B)\in\mathcal{M}$. Since the
set of all measurable rectangles generates the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{M}\otimes\mathcal{N}$,
it follows that $\theta$ is $\mathcal{M}/\mathcal{M}\otimes\mathcal{N}$-measurable.

Finally, note that the function $x\mapsto f(x,y)$ is the composition
$f\circ\theta$ of two measurable functions, so it is measurable too.